# Work with Maven, EJBs and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, ejb

I would like to build a Maven EJB project that generate EJB client to expose interfaces.

It works fine when I use this in my POM :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
        <generateClient>true</generateClient>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Two JARs are built in `target` but in Eclipse I have only one project for both implementations and interfaces.

I would like to create two separate projects in Eclipse, one for interfaces, one for implementations (the Eclipse traditional way when we create EJB project without Maven). How can I do this please?

Comment: How did you get your Maven project into Eclipse. M2E or are you using `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I succeeded by building with M2E in Eclipse 2 Maven Projects based on **maven-archetype-quickstart** archetype, one for ejb implementation (ejb-impl) and one for ejb client (ejb-client).

In ejb-impl, I choose packaging to `ejb` and in my ejb-client I choose `jar` packaging.

I use maven-ejb-plugin plugin to generate ejb from ejb-impl and I do NOT use generateClient option (default value is already set to false).

I use maven-ear-plugin to generate ear from ejb-impl, ejb-client and some war module (jsf). I use jarModule to include ejb-client so it's packaged under `lib` directory into ear file so no need to modify manifest or anything else, ejb-client cand be reached easily for others modules.

So, with Maven I can now use or distribute only interfaces methods of EJBs not implementations and there is no redundant code.